# Sequelize - how to insert data into multiple tables?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm new using Sequelize and I ran into a problem that I don't understand why it is happening. I am trying to create a new user, the user's data is defined in two tables. One is the user table that contains the general user's information like firstname, lastname, email etc.. The other table contains the user's settings like which color scheme the user wants to use etc.. The models for these tables look like this.

user model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: {
        args: true,
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }
);

  return User;
};
```

User settings model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const UserSettings = sequelize.define('user_settings', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        wants_update_notification: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false
        },
        color_scheme: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false 
        }
    });

    UserSettings.associate = (models) => {
        UserSettings.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'user' });
    };
    
    return UserSettings;
}
```

Now, when I try to create a new user the server gets the general user's information through the body of an endpoint. With this information the server creates a new user. Next I add the default user settings to the object that the created user returns and try to insert the data in the user settings table, like so:

```
let theUser = await sequelizeConnection.models.user.create(req.body);

theUser.wants_update_notification = false;
theUser.color_scheme = 0;

await sequelizeConnection.models.user_settings.create(theUser);
```

However, this returns the error: `user_settings.user_id cannot be null`. I find this strange because the user_id is returned by the create method of the user model. If I log the contents of `theUser` I can clearly see that there is a user_id present. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add wants_update_notification and color_scheme to the `user` instead of `user_settings`

```
let theUser = await sequelizeConnection.models.user.create(req.body); // theUser is a user model instance

theUser.wants_update_notification = false; // here!
theUser.color_scheme = 0;

await sequelizeConnection.models.user_settings.create(theUser);
```

Correct version:

```
await sequelizeConnection.sequelize.transaction(async(transaction) => {
        const createdUser = await sequelizeConnection.models.user.create(req.body, {transaction});

        const userSettings = {
            wants_update_notification: false,
            color_scheme: 0,
            user_id: createdUser.user_id, // Associate user with user_settings
        };
        await sequelizeConnection.models.user_settings.create(userSettings, {transaction});
});
```

I recommend that you use `sequelize.transaction` to get rollback in case of data creation failure.